# Why can't I save this QR code image in IOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, qr-code

Using this [QR Code](http://chesoo.com/qrcode/):

My Safari long press this picture can't be saved to the album, but using 3D-touch can save it in the album.

See

[image: My code]

Comment: try with JPG instead of PNG

Comment: Do you have access to the raw source code or just a screenshot? If you have access to the source, can you please provide that? That will make it easier for others to work with rather than having to re-type the whole thing

Comment: jpg can't be saved either.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-Hans">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection" />
    <title>QRcode</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="qrDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="imagQrDiv"></div>
    <script>
        $("#qrDiv").qrcode({
            width: 120, //宽度 
            height: 120, //高度 
            text: "111" //任意内容 
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        //从 canvas 提取图片 image
        function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
            //新Image对象，可以理解为DOM
            var image = new Image();
            // canvas.toDataURL 返回的是一串Base64编码的URL，当然,浏览器自己肯定支持
            // 指定格式 PNG
            image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            return image;
        }
        //获取网页中的canvas对象
        var mycanvas1 = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
        //将转换后的img标签插入到html中
        var img = convertCanvasToImage(mycanvas1);
        $('#imagQrDiv').append(img); //imagQrDiv表示你要插入的容器id
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: jpg can't be saved either.